# My JavaFx app perfomes quite slowly

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I am doing a JavaFx  project which is connected to documentum data storage . Recently I've noticed that at some specific points it performs quite slowly . Once it starts running it retrieves some data from documentum which is fairly fast considering the volume of data and creates instances of the class that I've defined in order to load them in to the table.(Till this point is still ok.) Here is my function for doing so :

```
public void createCheckbox() {
        List<String> columnnames = Arrays.asList("id", "name", "bg", "country","countryCode", "status",
                "incorporationDate","aclName","aclDomain");
        for (int i = 0; i <= columnnames.size() - 1  ; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
            column1.setPercentWidth(22.0);

            gridChkBoxContainer.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);
            CheckBox cbs = new CheckBox(columnnames.get(i));
            cbs.selectedProperty().set(true);
            gridChkBoxContainer.add(cbs, i, 0);
        }
    }


    public void createTable() {
        int count = 0 ;
        infoTable.getColumns().clear();
        CheckBox cb;
        ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridChkBoxContainer.getChildren();
        for (Node node : childrens) {
            cb = (CheckBox) node;
            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                TableColumn Col = new TableColumn(cb.getText());
                Col.prefWidthProperty().bind(infoTable.widthProperty().divide(6));
                Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Report, String>(cb.getText()));
                infoTable.getColumns().add(Col);
            }
        }

        try{
            infoTable.getItems().clear();
            if (txtKeyword.getText().compareTo("") == 0){


            strDQL = "select dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.name , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.bg_name , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.incorporation_date , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.status , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.country_name , cosec_general.acl_domain , cosec_general.acl_name , cosec_general.country_code from dm_dbo.cosec_general_view , cosec_general where dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id =cosec_general.comp_id";
            }else{
                strDQL = "select dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.name , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.bg_name , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.incorporation_date , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.status , dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.country_name , cosec_general.acl_domain , cosec_general.acl_name , cosec_general.country_code from dm_dbo.cosec_general_view , cosec_general where dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id =cosec_general.comp_id and ( UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id) like UPPER('@aclname') or  UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.name) like UPPER('@aclname')or  UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.bg_name) like UPPER('@aclname') or  UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.incorporation_date) like UPPER('@aclname')  or  UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.country_name) like UPPER('@aclname')  or  UPPER(dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.status) like UPPER('@aclname') or  UPPER(cosec_general.acl_name) like UPPER('@aclname')or  UPPER(cosec_general.acl_domain) like UPPER('@aclname')or  UPPER(cosec_general.country_code) like UPPER('@aclname') )";

                String searchVar = "%"+txtKeyword.getText()+"%";
                strDQL = strDQL.replace("@aclname", searchVar );

            }
            IDfQuery ACLQuery = new DfQuery();
            ACLQuery.setDQL(strDQL);
            IDfCollection col = ACLQuery.execute(_session, DfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);
            while (col.next()) {
                BGDetails bgInfo = new BGDetails(col.getString("comp_id"), col.getString("name"), col.getString("bg_name"),
                        col.getString("country_name"), col.getString("status"), col.getString("incorporation_date"),col.getString("acl_name"),col.getString("acl_domain"),col.getString("country_code"));

                infoTable.getItems().add(bgInfo);
                count++;

            }}catch(Exception e){
                Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.ERROR , "An Error was found!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }


    if (count == 0 ){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING , "No search result was found !");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }
    }
```

and then there is text field (fx:id="txtKeyword") on the top which is for searching through the data . It's worth mentioning that for this purpose instead of storing the data I've fetched earlier I would create and customize a new DQL to re-fetch from the data storage again . I've noticed that at this point it's not the data retrieving which takes long time to run , instead the keying in the word(s) into my search field is lagging noticeably. Or in other words every time I want to navigate through the app using keyboard or mouse it starts lagging and the other times is ok . Any idea how can I improve the speed of performance ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You state that the performance issues occur when you type in the text field - which code runs when you do? Presumably you have some `ChangeListener` registered for it? or is the `createTable` method called on every change to the text?

Comment: @sillyfly Once I click on the text field (txtKeyword) to trigger it to key in some text it lagges (in other words it takes a while for the text field to understand that I have clicked on it ) and while I am inserting data into that text field using keyboard the displayer is always far behind me (considering that my typing speed is not that high :D )

Comment: I understood that part, what I'm asking is - which part of your code is called for every key-press/every change of the text in the `TextField`? Is it the `createTable` method? Or some other code not included in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that has not to do with `JavaFX Thread` be done on an external `Thread`,especially database query stuff.

> Example structure of JavaFX Service[[tutorial]](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)(**the below is an example using SQLITE**):

```
public class DataLoader extends Service<Boolean> {

    int total;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DataLoader() {

        // if succeeded
        setOnSucceeded(s -> {
            //code if Service succeeds
        });

        // if failed
        setOnFailed(fail -> {
            //code it Service fails
        });

        //if canceled
        setOnCancelled(cancelled->{
            //code if Service get's cancelled
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
        return new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                // -------------------------- Load all the libraries
                try (ResultSet resultSet = connection1.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT* FROM LIBRARIES;");
                        ResultSet dbCounter = connection1.createStatement()
                                .executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIBRARIES;");) {

                    total = dbCounter.getInt(1);
                    Main.logger.info("Uploading libraries....");

                    // Refresh the text
                    Platform.runLater(() -> Main.updateScreen.label.setText("Uploading Libraries..."));
                    updateProgress(1, 2);

                    // Load all the libraries
                    while (resultSet.next()) {

                        Library library = new Library(resultSet.getString("NAME"), resultSet.getString("TABLENAME"),
                                resultSet.getDouble("STARS"), resultSet.getString("DATECREATED"),
                                resultSet.getString("TIMECREATED"), resultSet.getString("DESCRIPTION"),
                                resultSet.getInt("SAVEMODE"), resultSet.getInt("POSITION"),
                                resultSet.getString("LIBRARYIMAGE"), resultSet.getBoolean("OPENED"));

                        //Using Platform Later to Modify JavaFX Nodes
                        Platform.runLater(()->{
                           //code here
                        });

                        updateProgress(resultSet.getRow(), total);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Main.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
                    return false //something bad happened
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
    }

}
```